# Using VueJS in multipage WebForms project

Tags: c#, asp.net, vue.js, webforms, vuejs2

I have a webforms project which I'd like to use VueJS in but am having issues setting up the root element.

If i wrap my content in an `<div id="app"></div>` element and pass this to the Vue instance:

```
 new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        foo
    },
    data: {
    },
    methods: {
    }
});
```

With a test component such as:

```
var foo = Vue.component('foobar', {
    props: [
        'title'
    ],
    data: function () {
        return {
        };
    }
});
```

And an example component inline template:

```
<foobar inline-template title="Hello world">
    <div>
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    </div>
</foobar>
```

I end up with a Vue console error because it's trying to parse the entire contents of the page as a Vue template and it's failing on some script manager scripts with the error `[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:`:

```
<div id="app">
    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('ctl00$manScript', 'aspnetForm', 
['tctl00$ctxM','','tctl00$pnlMessagePlaceholder$pMP',''], [], [], 90, 
'ctl00');
//]]>
</script>
```

How can I include VueJS in a web forms project and avoid these template parse errors?

Comment: Have you tried referencing your bundle in the head of your webforms page? Then Vue should be able to inject the app into the #app element.

Comment: @Jelle - Sorry,  I'm not sure what you mean. The scripts are referenced in the head already, and i've just got the `<div id="app">` element wrapping the entire contents of the page, how would Vue inject the content in? I've got the components set up as `inline-template` types to allow them to be used in standard asp.net user controls.

Answer (score 0):

As far as Vue.js is concerned the code you provided works like this:

html file

```
<div id="app">
<foo-component title="Hello world">   
</foo-component>
</div>
```

javascript file

```
var foo = Vue.component('foo-component', {
    props: [
        'title'
    ],
    data: function () {
        return {
        };
    },
  template:` <div>
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    </div>`
    });

new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

You have registered the component as foo-component but then you called 'foobar'. Also, your Vue instance should be placed after you create the component so that it recognizes it.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - the `foobar` / `foo-component` is just a typo which i'll correct. The component is also created before the Vue instance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is an officially suggested solution to this. Probably just a bad practice to use it like so. One hacky way to get rid of the warning is to relocate you script tags using javascript to the bottom of the doc's body before your Vue code executes:

```
const scripts = document.querySelector('#app').querySelectorAll('script');
for (let i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
   document.body.appendChild(scripts[i]);
}
```

Comment: Whomever down-voted the answer, could please give a reason?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example. All it does it assemble the pieces you included in your question. It just works. I didn't encounter your issue so I don't know what you were doing wrong. Best to include an [example per our guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) another time, rather than just partial fragments--in our game, the devil is in the detail and it's often something silly, as I'm sure you know :)

I've put the js directly in the page for simplicity here, so this is the whole thing. (The code-behind is just the generated empty class).

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="scripts/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <div id="app">
                <foobar inline-template title="Hello world">
                    <div>
                        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
                    </div>
                </foobar>
                <script>
                    Vue.component('foobar', {
                        props: [
                            'title'
                        ],
                        data: function () {
                            return {
                            };
                        }
                    });
                    new Vue({
                        el: '#app',
                        //components: {
                        //    foo
                        //},
                        data: {
                        },
                        methods: {
                        }
                    });
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You've misunderstood the question - read the bit about Vue trying to parse the nested scripts within the root element e.g. webforms `<script>` tags generated by things like update panels etc... your example doesn't include this so of course it works. This is a really old question, I ended up solving my problem by having a Vue root per 'thing' instead of wrapping the whole page in a single root element.